# How include zeros when using count() + dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

The code I've got so far works fine, but I want to include in the output *certain* `Majors` with zero count. Having read around it looks like the solution is to include `.drop = FALSE` within `count()`, but I can't get it to work.

```
#DATA
Sum22_Graduation_MajorsALL <- data.frame(Sum_2022_Graduation.Major_1 =c('CRJS', 'CRJS', 
'ENGL', 'ENGL', 'JOE', 'DAN', 'HIST', 'PPE'), Sum_2022_Graduation.Major_2 =c('JOE', 'DAN', 'ENGL', 
'HIST', 'PPE', 'CRJS', 'CRJS', 'PPE'))
```

```
#CODE SO FAR
Sum22_selectCOHSSgrad <- Sum22_Graduation_MajorsALL %>%
    select(Sum_2022_Graduation.Major_1, Sum_2022_Graduation.Major_2) %>%
    pivot_longer(cols = everything(), names_to = NULL, values_to = 'Majors') %>%
    filter(Majors=='CRJS' | Majors=='ENGL' | Majors=='HIST' | Majors=='POLS' | Majors=='PPE') %>%
    count(Majors, name = "Count")
```

But because `POLS` does not occur in `Sum22_Graduation_MajorsALL`, the output just doesn't include `POLS` at all--whereas I would like it to include  `'POLS'.......0`. The documentation for `dplyr` *seems* to say that `count(Majors, name = "Count", .drop = FALSE)` should accomplish. I'm obviously using this incorrectly, but can someone kindly point out where is my error?

Thanks and happy thanksgiving!

Comment: please share the data

Comment: Thanks,@GuedesBF--it is included in first codebox (see `Sum22_Graduation_MajorsALL`)!

Comment: We would have to set the variable to a factor with a prespecified list of levels, as in the answer by SamR

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [docs](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/count.html) for `dplyr::count()` note that arguments can be passed through the ellipsis to [`dplyr::group_by()`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/count.html) which has the `.drop` parameter:

> `.drop` Drop groups formed by factor levels that don't appear in the data? The default is `TRUE`

In your case, make `Majors` a `factor`, specifying the `levels` explicitly. Then set `.drop = FALSE` in your `count()` call.

```r
subjects_of_interest <- c("CRJS", "ENGL", "HIST", "POLS", "PPE")

Sum22_Graduation_MajorsALL |>
    select(Sum_2022_Graduation.Major_1, Sum_2022_Graduation.Major_2) |>
    pivot_longer(cols = everything(), names_to = NULL, values_to = "Majors") |>
    filter(Majors %in% subjects_of_interest) |>
    mutate(Majors = factor(Majors, levels = subjects_of_interest)) |>
    count(Majors, name = "Count", .drop = FALSE)

# # A tibble: 5 × 2
#   Majors Count
#   <fct>  <int>
# 1 CRJS       4
# 2 ENGL       3
# 3 HIST       2
# 4 POLS       0
# 5 PPE        3
```

Incidentally you can do all this in base R without all the pivoting and grouping:

```r
unlist(Sum22_Graduation_MajorsALL) |>
    Filter(\(x) x %in% subjects_of_interest, x = _) |>
    factor(levels = subjects_of_interest) |>
    table(dnn = "Majors") |>
    as.data.frame(responseName = "Count")

#   Majors Count
# 1   CRJS     4
# 2   ENGL     3
# 3   HIST     2
# 4   POLS     0
# 5    PPE     3
```

Comment: Ah, that solution works great @SamR--thank you. And thanks, as well, for the helpful explanation. Cheers!